# LocalStorage.getItem Value returns null

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to toggle between a table and a graph. I have written a couple of functions save the state that the user switches to using localstorage. But when I console.log localStorage.getItem, i see the value as null. What am I missing? This is Vanilla Javascript

```
const data = document.querySelectorAll("button.data");
const dataTable = document.querySelector(".dataTable");
const dataGraph = document.querySelector(".dataGraph");

const ViewdataGraph = () => {
    dataTable.style.display = "none";
    dataGraph.style.display = "block";
    data.forEach(
        (element) => (element.innerText = "View data Table"));
   localStorage.setItem("dataViewType", "Graph");

}

const ViewdataTable = () => {
    dataGraph.style.display = "none";
    dataTable.style.display = "block";
    data.forEach(
        (element) => (element.innerText = "View data Graph"));
   localStorage.setItem("dataViewType", "table");

}

const Toggledata = () => {
    const dataType = localStorage.getItem("dataViewType");

    if (dataType) {
        if (dataType === "table") {
            ViewdataTable();

        } else if (dataType === "Graph") {
            ViewdataGraph();

        }
    }
};

 


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

    const data = document.querySelectorAll("button.data");
    data.forEach((element) =>
        element.addEventListener("click", (event) => ToggleData()),
    );
}
```

Comment: You are using localStorage..setItem("dataViewType", "table"), there is double dot check you console, It will throw an error

Comment: Have you set your localStorage item initially? If you plan to use it as a toggle, it would be necessary to set the `dataViewType` beforehand.

Comment: check if the dataViewType is saved to local storage, if you're using Chrome, inspect the page, choose application and click on local storage..

Comment: @sulaimon-olaniran I just checked and it isn't saved.

Answer (score 0):

on your code  only I see that you have 2 dots on this line of code `localStorage..setItem("dataViewType", "table");` change to this `localStorage.setItem("dataViewType", "table");`
I hope this is your problem

Comment: Thank you, I have removed that. But I still have the same result

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `ViewdataTable` function.

`localStorage.setItem("dataViewType", "table");`

Also, there's a problem in `Toggledata`, when localStorage has no `dataViewType` item, the variable `dataType` will be `null`, hence no changes will be made to your view or `localStorage`. I suggest using an array of views and storing the index of the active view.

```js
const views = [
    { elem: dataTable, name: 'Table' },
    { elem: dataGraph, name: 'Graph' },
];

let viewIndex = -1;

const Toggledata = () => {
    views[viewIndex].elem.style.display = "none";
    viewIndex++;

    // wrapping
    if (viewIndex >= views.length) {
        viewIndex = 0;
    }

    const view = views[viewIndex];
    view.elem.style.display = "block";
    data.forEach(element => (element.innerText = `View data ${view.name}`));
    localStorage.setItem("dataViewType", String(viewIndex));
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const data = document.querySelectorAll("button.data");
    data.forEach((element) =>
        element.addEventListener("click", (event) => ToggleData()),
    );

    // use first view if dataViewType is not set
    viewIndex = Number(localStorage.getItem("dataViewType") || "0");

    // not a valid value
    if (Number.isNaN(viewIndex) || !(viewIndex in views)) {
        viewIndex = 0;
    }

    // maybe not necessary if HTML style sets display to none by default
    views.forEach(v => (v.elem.style.display = 'none'));
    views[viewIndex].elem.style.display = 'block';
}
```